# How to add checkbox to each drop down value for Select Control

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular JS 1 ,

I am displaying values dynamically into select control .

This is my code

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/454/

Comment: You should create custom select tag to obtain this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a `<select>`, just use a ng-repeat to display your checkboxes:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
  $scope.selectedNames = [];
  
  $scope.select = function(name) {
      var index = $scope.selectedNames.indexOf(name);
      if(index < 0)
        $scope.selectedNames.push(name);
      else
          $scope.selectedNames.splice(index, 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="n in names">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(n)"/>{{n}}
  </div> 
  selected: {{selectedNames}}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you , is it possible to add this under drop down ?

Comment: @Pawan Yep, using `<ul>`, `<li>` in  a dropdown. [**Example with Bootstrap here**](http://jsfiddle.net/prakash38/kvmkbb82/17/).